# Is it possible to put Firefox into full screen mode programmatically?

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, fullscreen, splinter

I'm testing something using Splinter / Selenium, using the Firefox webdriver.

I'd like to automate getting the browser into full screen mode. I've tried mozRequestFullScreen but it won't co-operate - I get errors about it not being triggered by a user event (presumably this is a security thing). Is there a way to run Firefox where it will allow this? Or a profile setting or something?

Comment: I don't know Splinter and I don't know Python. But in pure WebDriver in Java, this works for me: `driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")).sendKeys(Keys.F11);`. It simply presses F11 programatically in WebDriver. Can you maybe mimic it in Python?